# docker-compose up Permission denied on Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  backend:
    tty: true
    build:
      context: project/backend
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=*/api/*,https://*/api/*
      - VIRTUAL_HOST_WEIGHT=42
```

If I try to do

```
docker-compose up
```

on windows at somepoint I get:

```
[91m/bin/sh: 1: ./mvnw: Permission denied
[0m[31mERROR[0m: Service 'backend' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c ./mvnw package' returned a non-zero code: 126
```

I am using Windows 10 64 bit Professional
Anybody has an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug with docker-compose.  When building on Windows, the regular `docker build` command will set all files to `-rwxr-xr-x`, but it looks like docker-compose is not doing this.  It will be fixed in the next release of compose.

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3065#issuecomment-191489901

The workaround, as suggested by dnephin is to add `RUN chmod +x your/files` to the end of your dockerfile.

Comment: Hi Jarrod, do you know if this has been fixed in the new release? I am getting a similar error almost at the first step of a tutorial (https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution/)
I get /bin/sh: 1: ./docker/composer.sh: Permission denied even after chmod +x on all the specified file.